# Process.Start(screenreaderPath) not staying on screen

Tags: vb.net

```
Private Sub Button8_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button8.Click
    Dim screenreaderPath As String = IO.Path.Combine(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.System), "help.exe")
    Process.Start(screenreaderPath)
```

When I click the button it loads but won't stay on screen. Instead, it just disappears. Can anyone explain why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since this is a command line app you can load cmd.exe directly and pass it the /k argument which tells Windows to leave the cmd open:

```
Private Sub Button8_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button8.Click
    Dim screenreaderPath As String = IO.Path.Combine(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.System), "help.exe")
    Dim oProcess As New Process
    Dim pi As ProcessStartInfo = New ProcessStartInfo()

    pi.Arguments = " /k """ & screenreaderPath & """"
    pi.FileName = "cmd.exe"
    oProcess.StartInfo = pi
    oProcess.Start()
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks for the help it worked great. Sorry for the late reply